# Handling dollars in rails with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a rails 4 application that has a form with many dollar input fields (all inside the same model).
I've made all of the fields decimals with precision => 10 and scale => 2. The issue I'm having is the input fields are masked with commas separating every '000'. I need to parse the commas out of all of these inputs before validating and saving to the database.

I need to store the value in the database as '150,000.00' so an external service can read the dollar value.

```
# Params
Parameters: {"requested_amount"=>"150,000.00"}

# SQL Update
SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "requested_amount", "150.0"
```

With my current configuration, the database only saves what comes before the comma. I need to remove the comma so the SQL update can pass through the proper value.

Is there a gem that can do something like this? I've read into the rails-money gem and it seems a bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the money gem.

I just got done writing a financial application and it's the way to go.

Comment: I'll take another look at it. It seems pretty overkill the first time I looked at it but thanks!

Comment: Oh I promise it's not. Dealing with formatting is a big pain. This makes it super simple. You put some code in the model and your forms behave as you'd expect them to and the information is saved in an integer column it's super easy.

Comment: Just going through the docs now- a little confused. Do I need to use the add_money helper when changing the column types? Also, I have one model with many fields that require dollar inputs, the examples money-rails shows are one field per model? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is some info missing.

What are you using to create the form?
Do you have verified if the value in the database is storing with commas?

Look at [simple form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to generate the form

Comment: I added some more information. I have the form with all of the fields built already. The specific issue is that between the params hash and updating the database, the comma forces the DB to only accept the numbers before the comma. I need to strip the comma out before it saves to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the money-rails gem is overkill, here's one approach:

- Use integer column type to store money amount as cents, so 15000000 is stored.
- Have a getter method to return a formatted value of the column, i.e. '150,000.00'